# C++ cannot pass objects of non-POD type

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, codeblocks

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    ifstream llfile;
    llfile.open("C:/log.txt");

    if(!llfile.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    string word;
    llfile >> word;
    llfile.close();
    string url = "http://example/auth.php?ll=" + word;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my error when compiling:

> main.cpp|29|warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type `'struct std::string'` through `'...'`; call will abort at runtime

Comment: +1 for an SSCCE, -1 for not actually asking a question. Uh, +0 I guess...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem you have is that variable argument functions do not work on non-POD types, including `std::string`. That is a limiation of the system and cannot be modified. What you can, on the other hand, is change your code to pass a POD type (in particular a pointer to a nul terminated character array):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

Answer (score 12):

As the warning indicates, `std::string` is not a POD-type, and POD-types are required when calling variadic-argument functions (i.e., functions with an `...` argument).

However, `char const*` is appropriate here; change

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```

to

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```